# Dismiss UIView when tapped outside the view

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a button say buttonA in my one of my tableview cells which when tapped displays a view say view1. View1 dismisses only when I tap on the button. However I want that view1 to be dismissed when I tap outside the view.

I have tried with :

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissDropdownView))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

.

```
@objc func dismissDropdownView() {
        dropDownView.isHidden = true
    }
```

The issue I'm facing with the above is that when I tap on other buttons(other than buttonA) in my tableview cell, they do not perform required action.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Xcode 11.5 @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of your `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `false`.